# Unexpected end of file. Gzip compressed file

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I am going crazy with a gzip file.

I can decompress the file in Windows using WinRAR but it is impossible on any UNIX operating system.

the file seems to be ok. If I do

```
file the_name_of_the_file.gz
```

I get:

```
the_name_of_the_file.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sun Jan 30 14:10:21 2011
```

But if I do

```
gunzip -f the_name_of_the_file.gz
```

I alsways get:

```
gzip: the_name_of_the_file.gz: unexpected end of file
```

The same problem happens when I try to extract the file using the GUI tool in Ubuntu or MacOSX,

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the same exact file (i.e. You have it on a flash drive and have opened it up from the two operating systems) or are you downloading it individually?  If the later, you could have an incomplete download that doesn't have all of the data (aka, corrupt).

Comment: The `file` command won't check all of the file. It'll just look at a few bytes in the header to figure out that it's a `gz` encoded file.

Comment: It is not corrupted because I have tried first in Unix and later in Windows.

Comment: Did you make the gzip file? If so, what operating system and application did you use to create the gzip file?

Answer (score 10):

A workaround for uncompressing a file when `gzip` fails with "unexpected end of file" is to use `zcat` (also usually provided by the gzip package of your distribution).

`$ zcat file.raw.gz > file.raw`

Answer (score 2):

Did you by any chance transfer the file from Win* to Unix via ftp in ascii mode? That may explain it. Is the file the same size on Win* and Unix?

Comment: I have tried tu decompress the file first in Windows and later in Unix.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're corrupting the file when copying it to the *nix machine.

FTP it in binary mode.

Comment: I think the file is not corrupted because I tried to gunzip it fist in unix and later in Windows.

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense. If you didn't need to create a copy of the file, then say so. If you did, maybe your copying process (FTP?) was incorrect.

Comment: I transfered the file via USB pendrive. I tried first in UNIX and it didn't work and then I tried in Windows and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem using the utility [P7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/), a port of 7za.exe for POSIX systems.

Comment: So, you're saying the archived file used a compression method that is not recognized by legacy Unix tools?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and, in my case, it was due to the fact that the file was an empty (0 bytes) `gz` file, created with the `touch` command:

```
$touch file.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 2016-05-24 11:48 file.txt
```

gzip could not decompress it, when called with the command:

```
$gzip -dv file.txt.gz
gzip: file.txt.gz: unexpected end of file
```

The correct way to represent an empty `txt` file would have been generating first the `txt` file, then compress it and, finally, decompress it:

```
$touch file.txt

$gzip -v file.txt
file.txt:         0.0% -- replaced with file.txt.gz

$gzip -dv file.txt.gz
file.txt.gz:      0.0% -- replaced with file.txt
```

I don't know if this scenario represents your case, but it may give you some clue or help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few experiences with WinRar, my *first guess* is that it's extracting incomplete or corrupted files without giving an error, while gzip is (correctly) giving an error.

What does [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) make of your file?

What version does `gzip -V` announce?

What does `gzip -t the_name_of_the_file.gz` tell you?  (probably the same unexpected EOF, but worth a try)

Comment: gzip -V: gzip 1.3.12,, gzip -t the_name_of_the_file -> unexpected EOF

Answer (score 0):

Check if the destination has enough space where you want to copy the file. If still doesn't work try creating the file using 'touch' and give permission to 777 in the destination.

Comment: Read the other answers, they solved the problem when they use another tool.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1121246)